# form API : date format is not applied in the input

Tags: 8, forms, datetime

I use the [Form API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api) to build forms in custom module.

Forms works fine but my custom date format is not applied.

Here is an extract of my form code :

```
$form['date_debut'] = array(
            '#type' => 'date',
            '#title' => $this->t('Date de début'),
            '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
            '#description' => t('Cliquez dans le champ et sélectionnez une date de début de congé dans le calendrier'),
            '#required' => TRUE
        );
```

The date format is `d/m/Y`

But i still see `Y/m/d` in the input :

[image]

In the DOM, the date format is d/m/Y `data-drupal-date-format="d/m/Y"`

```
<input type="text" data-drupal-selector="edit-date-fin" aria-describedby="edit-date-fin--description" data-drupal-date-format="d/m/Y" class="form-date required form-control hasDatepicker" id="edit-date-fin" name="date_fin" value="" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

When the form is validated, i display a message with the date picker value and the date format is `Y/m/d`

```
drupal_set_message($this->t('Vous avez choisi comme date de début : @date_debut', array('@date_debut' => $form_state->getValue('date_debut'))));
```

See :

[image]

Am i missing something? How can i modify this date format visible by the user in the input and in the Drupal message ?

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in?  This question may be a duplicate, too.

Comment: @mpdonadio you’re right. I didn’t noticed that but i see this issue in Chrome OSX and not on firefox OSX. It seems to be a browser issue ?

Comment: @mpdonadio i guess it is a duplicate of this question : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/243286/wrong-date-field-format-in-chrome Should i delete my question ?

Comment: Yeah, this is a HTML5 input element complication.  That may not be the best question about this.  I'll dig.  Leave this for now, and we'll close as dup if needed.  Otherwise, I will write up a proper answer.

Comment: Try '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y' instead of  '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y'

Comment: @YogeshKushwaha sorry, it doesn’t work, date format is no longer applied on other browsers which previously had no issue